# Javascript or OLD JQuery accordion multiples on one page without toggling each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make reusable Javascript chunks and keeping hitting a wall.  This is the currently annoying one, but I have a slideshow with the same basic problem.  I've googled it a few times, but I don't think I'm using the right words...

**The Goal:** Make a div with class accord.  Inside have several divs (not always the same number) with class of accordionItem.  Have the first of the accordion items in each accord div be visible while the rest toggle closed (a div inside accordionItem changes visibility, and a h4 acts as the cue.)  When you click on a non-visible section it toggles to visible and the old one toggles closed.  I want more then one of these on a page, and have their visibilitys and toggle not effect each other.  I don't need any animations or any complex behaviors.

**Largest Limitation:**  I'm currently stuck using a site that can't go above jQuery 1.4.2 (moving up breaks the main page menu and the IT department doesn't want to deal with fixing it, and I don't have access) So I can't call a higher version without breaking the menu, but finding an accordion script (or anything else) that works on the site is a pain.

**Other limitation,** I prefer the accordion if it breaks, break with all pieces visible, that way all the info is still available. These are being used to make the page shorter, but we need the info accessible.

**How I've been working around the issue.**  I'm copying the javascript and making another one with changed class names each time I need a new acccordion, which is ridiculous, but I don't understand javascript well enough to do anything else.  I play more in html and css so didn't build this javascript.  I have the same basic problem with a slideshow, it works with the jquery I'm stuck with, but I can't figure out how to keep two instances of the slideshow from sucking into one.

I know I want it to basically for each accord div hide all the accordionItems, unhide the first one, and when I click on a different one only change that specific accord I'm on.  Alternately, if it inserted ids dynamically (so I don't have to input them into the page code) and ran it that way it would be fine as well.  I'm trying to make it so someone who doesn't know how the code works could easily utilize it.

CSS and Javascript;

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<style>

      .accordionItem h4 { margin: 0;  font-size: 15px;  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px; color: #fff; background: url('/images/image.aspx?iid=10691') right center no-repeat #fff;color: #a50050;  font-weight:600; font-family: 'Lucida Sans', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; line-height: normal;}
      .accordionItem h4:hover { cursor: pointer; }
      .accordionItem div { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0.4em; background-color: rgba(165, 0, 80,.05); border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
      .accordionItem.hide h4 { color: #a50050; background-color: #fff; font-weight:400; background: url('/images/image.aspx?iid=10690') right center no-repeat; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
      .accordionItem.hide div { display: none; }  

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var accordionContainers = new Array();// ADDED BY ME
    var accordionItems = new Array();


    function init() {

    //Find each accordion ADDED BY ME
    var accordDivs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < accordDivs.length; i++) {
        if (accordDivs[i].className == 'accord') accordionContainers.push( accordDivs[i] );
        }

      // Grab the accordion items from each div 
      var divs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
      for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( divs[i].className == 'accordionItem' ) accordionItems.push( divs[i] );
      }

      // Assign onclick events to the accordion item headings
      for ( var i = 0; i < accordionItems.length; i++ ) {
        var h4 = getFirstChildWithTagName( accordionItems[i], 'H4' );
        h4.onclick = toggleItem;
      }

      // Hide all accordion item bodies except the first
      for ( var i = 1; i < accordionItems.length; i++ ) {
        accordionItems[i].className = 'accordionItem hide';
      }
    }

    function toggleItem() {
      var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;

      // Hide all items
      for ( var i = 0; i < accordionItems.length; i++ ) {
        accordionItems[i].className = 'accordionItem hide';
      }

      // Show this item if it was previously hidden
      if ( itemClass == 'accordionItem hide' ) {
        this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem';
      }
    }

    function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
      }
    }

    //}

     //]]>
       window.onload = function()
      {
      init();
     };

    </script>
```

I figured out how to find all the accord divs on the page, but couldn't figure out what to do with them.

Example Stripped down Accordions:  (This code works, but all accordionItems are considered the same so all toggle together.  The surrounding div accord wasn't in the original javascript, I added it in the beginning while trying to figure out how to toggle one section at a time.  )

```
    <div style="width:50%">
    <div class="accord">
    <div class="accordionItem">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Copy to Initially Show</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionItem">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Copy to hide</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionItem">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Copy to Hide </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- END accord-->

<p>Blah blah blah to break up the page<p>
<div class="accord">
    <div class="accordionItem">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Copy to Initially Show</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionItem">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Copy to hide</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionItem">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Copy to Hide </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- END accord-->
</div>
```

Thanks for any replies, especially those with long winded explanations about what ridiculously obvious piece I'm missing...  I also love examples.

Comment: what is the ie compatibility required

Comment: using jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zpz5tkr5/4/

Comment: Using javascript : http://jsbin.com/basokebigu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: IE isn't an issue, just that does work with jQuery 1.4.2, or basic javascript.  I'm not attached to my accordion, this is the only one i found I could get to work without breaking the site I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < accordionItems.length; i++ ) {
        var h4 = getFirstChildWithTagName( accordionItems[i], 'H4' );
        h4.onclick = toggleItem;
 }
```

Here `accordionItems` contains the entire list of accordionItems.

In the `toggleItem` function, you're again iterating through the entire list and toggling the class `hide`. Instead you need to identify the target and look for it's parentNode. And within that parentNode alone you must toggle the class.

You need to change the `toggleItem` function like this:

```
  function toggleItem() {

  var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;

  var accord =  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("div");

 // get that parent alone and it's children div

  for ( var i = 0; i < accord.length; i++ ) {
    accord[i].className = 'accordionItem hide';
  }


  // Show this item if it was previously hidden
  if ( itemClass == 'accordionItem hide' ) {
     this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem';
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/basokebigu/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: This is really really close to what I need it to do.  Only thing it doesn't do is open the initial accordionItem of each accord.  It only opens the first one, which is probably something about the order of the functions?  Or do I need to rewrite the getFirstChildWithTagName function.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel comfortable using jQuery (as it's already included on your page) then there is a fairly straight forward solution available. I've included a [demo page](http://jsbin.com/hitugateji/2/edit?js,output) showing how this can be done simply in jQuery.

I commented it to explain each step. If you put it into production you'll likely want to remove a few of the less useful ones. You'll notice that the main methods that I chose to use were [.closest(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector) and .children(selector).

Method `.closest()` is useful for finding the parent element of the target according to a selector (in this case I found the closest `.accord` since it is the parent of the sibling `.accordianItem`s). This is important because we don't want to toggle the other `.accordianItem`s' divs that aren't related. The parent `.accord` isolates the siblings from the rest of the elements on the page that share the same class.

Method `.children()` is useful for finding only the immediate children which match the given selector. This is useful for grabbing only the immediate child `div`. Something to keep in mind is sometimes people choose to use a specific class for the part of the content that should be hidden so as to avoid accidentally hiding other elements. An example of this is if we were to add a footer as such:

```
<div class="collapse-item">
  <h4>Header</h4>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

When hiding the content (in this case `.content`) and we don't want to hide our footer we would instead use the selector `.content` instead of `div` when searching via `.children()`. Just something to think about.

Comment: Additional links since I couldn't post them in my answer as I don't have enough reputation: [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector), [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: It's pretty, and does work, but it doesn't work in jQuery 1.4.2, which has been my problem with most of the other accordions I found.  Something was changed near that release about visibility, that breaks the page menu anytime we try to call it.

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally forgot to set the script reference to 1.4.2, it has been updated with a working example (in my original post), the html side is pulling in 1.4.2 now.